# no public authentication method ubuntu server raspberry pi 4

Tags: server, ssh

I have made a file named ssh in the sd card so it enables ssh without me plugging it into a monitor.
I am able to connect to the raspberry using putty, but when I try to log in it says "no supported authentication method".

How can I get rid of this error without plugging it into a monitor?

Comment: Exactly which release of Ubuntu Server did you install? Please link to whatever instructions you followed to install it.

Comment: @user535733 Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS 64bit  https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi